# Form save in django-selectable

Tags: python, django, forms

Im using [django-selectable](http://django-selectable.readthedocs.org) plugin. From the [docs](http://django-selectable.readthedocs.org) :

> in the case of lookups extending from Lookups Based on Models newly created items have not yet been saved into the database and saving should be handled by the form

Model:

```
class UserSettings(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='own_user')
   lookup_user = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile, related_name='other_user')
   category = models.ManyToManyField(NewsCategory)
   tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

Form:

```
class UserSettingsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    category = TreeNodeChoiceField(
    required=False,
    queryset=NewsCategory.objects.filter(status=True, is_deleted =False), label=u"Kategori", widget=forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'class':'uniformselect'})
    )
    class Meta:
        model = UserSettings
        exclude = ['user']
        widgets = {
            'lookup_user': selectable.AutoCompleteSelectMultipleWidget(lookup_class=UserLookUp,),
            'tag': selectable.AutoCompleteSelectMultipleWidget(lookup_class=TagLookUp,),
    }
```

lookup:

```
class UserLookUp(ModelLookup):
    model = UserProfile
    search_fields = ('first_name__icontains', )

    filters = {'is_active': True, }

    def get_item_value(self, item):
        return item.get_full_name()

    def get_item_label(self, item):
        return u"(%s)" % (item.get_full_name())

registry.register(UserLookUp)



@login_required
class TagLookUp(ModelLookup):
    model = Tag
    search_fields = ('slug__icontains', )


    def get_item_value(self, item):
        return item.name

    def get_item_label(self, item):
        return u"(%s)" % (item.name)

registry.register(TagLookUp)
```

and view:

```
def user_settings(request):
    try:
       set = UserSettings.objects.filter(blabla)[0]
    except:
       set = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserSettingsForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.user = user
            obj.save()
            form.save_m2m()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = UserSettingsForm(instance=set)
    return render_to_response('main/settings.html', {'form':form,},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Error:

```
TypeError at /news/settings/
int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/news/settings/
Django Version: 1.4
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'
Exception Location: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py in get_prep_value, line 537
```

With django-selectable, form couldnt save with this view. How can I save form with this plugin?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why couldn't it save? Did you get an error? Was the form not seen as valid?

Comment: This is only half of the stack trace (at best). It doesn't indicate which field couldn't be saved.

Comment: request.POST.items() [(u'category', u'6'), (u'usersettings', u'Send'), (u'tag_0', u''), (u'tag_1', u'2'), (u'lookup_user_0', u''), (u'lookup_user_1', u'4'), (u'csrfmiddlewaretoken', u'LucbEB0CHcjyFxEhqePA4dRW3VCJKqSu')] but error is after after form = UserSettingsForm(request.POST)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve this problem by replacing this:

```
category = TreeNodeChoiceField(
    required=False,
    queryset=NewsCategory.objects.filter(status=True, is_deleted =False), label=u"Kategori", widget=forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'class':'uniformselect'})
    )
```

by this:

```
category = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=NewsCategory.objects.filter(parent__isnull=False, status=True, is_deleted=False)
```